# If $H$ is a subgroup of a group G show that $Z (G)$ is a subset of $N (H)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

My answer is : let $x \in Z (G)$ i.e $xg = gx$ for all $g \in G$
But H is a subgroup of G so let h in H. Hence h in G 
So $xh =hx$ for all h in H , which means $xH =Hx$ 
So x in N (H).

Comment: That's pretty much all there is to it. Conjugation by an element $x \in Z(G)$ fixes $H$ pointwise, so it certainly fixes $H$ as a subgroup, which means that $x$ normalizes $H$.

Comment: Please answer your own question, since it seems to be solved. You can accept your own answer some time  after it is typed, and hence close this question.